# Last record row count in one to many laravel

Tags: laravel

**I have a one to many relationship**

shipment

| id | bill |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2222 |
| 2 | 4255 |

shipment_status

| id | status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | created |
| 1 | Shipped |
| 2 | created |
| 2 | Shipped |
| 2 | Delivered |
| 3 | created |
| 3 | Shipped |
| 4 | Created |
| 4 | Shipped |
| 4 | Delivered |
| 5 | Created |

What I want to get

Results

| count | status |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | Shipped |
| 2 | Delivered |
| 1 | Created |

What I've done :

```
SELECT  a.status, 
        b.total_status 
FROM    hipmenthistories a 
INNER JOIN (  
             SELECT status, 
                    MAX(created_at) last_status,
                    COUNT(*) total_status  
             FROM shipmenthistories
             GROUP   BY status 
            ) b ON a.status = b.status`
```

Actual data in the [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=065c69d0a24038225ef17d24b17083c7)

Answer (score 1):

Use [ROW_NUMBER()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) and order the results by shipment and most recent status date. Then filter on the most recent status row:

See also [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8a6f6dca4a0555e05064727c527cce94)

```
WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT status
          , shipment_id
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY shipment_id ORDER BY created_at DESC, id DESC) AS rowNum
   FROM   shipmenthistories
)
SELECT status, COUNT(shipment_id) numOfShipments 
FROM   CTE
WHERE  RowNum = 1
GROUP BY status;
```

Comment: Hi @sos how to do this in laravel eloquent

Comment: Sorry, I'm only familiar with MySQL, not laravel eloquent.